# Tamaños de alto y ancho dispositivos Android

Tags: android

Estimados, debo cortar las imágenes de fondo para mis aplicación en Android, actualmente tengo pensado cortarlas en este tamaño

```
Size     Width   Height 
------   -----   -------
MDPI   : 320px   480px
HDPI   : 480px   800px
XHDPI  : 720px   1280px
XXHDPI : 960px   1600px
XXXHDPI: 1280px  1920px
```

¿Pero que tamaños puede ser más recomendable?

Answer (score 0):

Hay un programa hecho en Java para eso está en github, es siempre recomendado(Hasta donde sé) tener las imagenes en todos los tamaños posibles, ya que el escalado a veces no funciona como debería, este programa puedes compilarlo o simplemente usar el jar, te permite seleccionar tanto los tamaños de entrada como los de salida, este es el link de github, su uso es muy simple, saludos.

[Final Android Resizer](https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer/blob/master/Executable%20Jar/Final%20Android%20Resizer.jar)

Comment: Tu programa corta las imágenes para los teléfonos, pero los tamaños cambian para las tablets, entonces faltaría saber cuales son los tamaños recomendables para las tablets.

Comment: @AlbertBarrientos el programa mantiene la relación de aspecto, si quieres por ejemplo que tenga esos tamaños(720px*1280px, 960px   1600px, etc.) tu imágen de entrada tendrá que tener 1280*1920 o uno que tenga la misma relación de aspecto, si el programa hiciera eso de forma automatica, tus imagenes se verían horribles, por ejemplo intenta convertir un cuadrado en Illustrator a 720*1280, es exactamente lo mismo.